# Derivative via a relative increment

Tags: calculus

Is there a name for a "relative derivative" given by the expression

$x\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x + h \cdot x)-f(x)}{h}$?

In reply to the comment by @patrickh

$ x\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = x \cdot \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f(x + k)-f(x)}{k} = lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f(x + k)-f(x)}{k/x} = \lim_{h=k/x\to 0} \frac{f(x + h \cdot x)-f(x)}{h} $

Comment: I don't believe you are using the partial derivative correctly as you are simply taking a normal derivative on the left hand side and multiplying by x. What you have written on the right hand side does not seem to be equivalent to this.

Comment: I.e. What you have written in its current form does not make much sense.

Comment: @patrickh Please see edit which shows the equivalence

Comment: As I stated before your use of a partial derivative is incorrect as the function is of one variable. What is the use of this equivalence?

Comment: I believe the partial derivative of a single-variable function with respect to that variable _is_ the ordinary derivative, so technically the equations above are correct. That said, it's probably better to use the notation of the ordinary derivative, since using partial-derivative notation makes it _look_ like you're trying to do something different than what you really want. At any rate, you've shown that the by multiplying the $h$ in the numerator by a quantity, you multiply the derivative by the same quantity. I'm not sure why there would be a special name for multiplying by $x$.

Comment: @patrickh You can think of other variables, i.e. $x_1$, $x_2$, etc, as not being shown since they don't make any difference to the point.

Comment: @ David K  To me the expression looks like a directional derivative of $f$ along $x$ in one dimension, so it seems that there is a name for it. I just wanted to confirm if others also view it like that.